# How do I stop my ROG Falchion wireless keyboard from rebooting Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, power-management, reboot, wireless-keyboards

I have recently purchased a ROG Falchion RGB wireless keyboard for use with my dual boot desktop (Win 10/Ubuntu 21.04). In Windows, using Armoury Crate, I have configured the lighting and set the power options for the keyboard to sleep after 2 minutes of idle time. What I have found is, when using Ubuntu, after the idle time has expired, instead of the keyboard going to sleep, the entire system goes into hibernation and the OS will restart unless you wake it and cancel the reboot. Currently, the only option to resolve the issue is to turn off the keyboard's power saving options in Armoury Crate. As this is not ideal, does anyone have any advice or thoughts on keeping power saving options on without causing the shutdown issues in Ubuntu?

Comment: That's a very strange problem, indeed. Sadly, there is no official support for Aura functionality on any Linux distribution right now besides a couple open-source alternatives and none of them directly manage power options. Your best bet right now would be to turn off the power saving options until better support is introduced into Xmodmap. A similar problem happens on ROG laptopts as well: https://www.linux.org/threads/keyboard-issues-with-asus-rog.34151/

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreTeles. Turning off the power saving options seems to be the only way for now. I also found out if you turn off the keyboard with its on/off switch on the back, it will immediately trigger an OS shutdown.

Comment: I landed here because on Ubuntu, when the keyboards goes to sleep, it puts the machine to sleep as well. So funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more permanent solution, append the following config to  /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier         "disable asus falchion sys control"
    MatchIsKeyboard    "on"
    MatchProduct       "ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION System Control"
    Option             "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

Before doing the above, you can verify the `MatchProduct` key by looking through your inputs with `xinput`.  You'll see that under the hood, Falchion is registering several inputs.  That `... System Control` input is the one it's using to tell your system to hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. ran the following:

#xinput disable XX

XX being the device id related to 'ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION System Control'

Also, created a startup script with this line

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the xinput ID worked fine for me, too. However, the ID can change in certain situations, so I wrote a script to determine the correct ID before disabling it:

```
#!/bin/bash
IDENTIFIER="ASUSTeK ROG FALCHION System Control"

LINE=$(xinput list | grep "$IDENTIFIER")
ID=$(echo ${LINE#*id=} | tr '\t' ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f1)

if [ -n "$ID" ]; then
    xinput disable $ID
    echo "Disabled xinput ID $ID ($IDENTIFIER)"
else
    echo "No xinput ID for '$IDENTIFIER' found."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Wayland or system-wide fix you can use the hwdb snippet from my gist and follow the instructions.   https://gist.github.com/jnettlet/afb20a048b8720f3b4eb8506d8b05643

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1190531)

Answer (score 0):

One way that works is to make sure all the Power related keyboard shortcuts are disabled for your *Nix distro.  Should be able to find them in your Settings.
Works for Fedora 34 and 35 with my Falchion.

Comment: Can you expand on "find them in your Settings"?