# Why does PC turn off when wireless keyboard sleeps

Tags: keyboard, suspend, shutdown

I have a ROG Falchion wireless keyboard. When booted into Ubuntu 20.04.3, the computer will suspend by itself. At first I thought this was a power setting. Nope. I noticed that the exact time my  keyboard goes to sleep, my PC suspends. If I use the USB cable, the problem resolves. Has anyone else had this issue? Or have heard of this issue? I can't seem to find anything about it.

It's a fresh install. The only change I've done is install VSCode and python3-pip.

Comment: Had the same. Check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351203/how-do-i-stop-my-rog-falchion-wireless-keyboard-from-rebooting-ubuntu) post.